# Using FakeItEasy to assert that an event was raised

Tags: .net, unit-testing, events, mocking, fakeiteasy

I can do the following to verify if the `ErrorOccurred` event of my `Consumer` class was raised:

```
using System;
using FakeItEasy;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

public interface IService
{
    event EventHandler SomethingBadHappened;
}

class Consumer
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public Consumer(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        service.SomethingBadHappened += (sender, args) => RaiseErrorOccurred();
    }

    public event EventHandler ErrorOccurred;

    protected virtual void RaiseErrorOccurred()
    {
        var handler = ErrorOccurred;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var service = A.Fake<IService>();
        var consumer = new Consumer(service);

        bool eventWasRaised = false;
        consumer.ErrorOccurred += (sender, args) => { eventWasRaised = true; };

        service.SomethingBadHappened += Raise.WithEmpty();

        Assert.IsTrue(eventWasRaised);
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a more "Mocking Framework-y" way of doing this. Something like the below would be nice:

```
        var service = A.Fake<IService>();
        var consumer = new Consumer(service);

        service.SomethingBadHappened += Raise.WithEmpty();

        consumer.ErrorOccurred.MustHaveHappened(/*yada yada/*);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For FakeItEasy to perform any assertions on methods, the method must be fakeable, and defined on a fake object. In this case, `consumer` is a "real" object, so there's no way for FakeItEasy to know whether it did anything.

There's an alternative, but whether it's more "Mocking Framework-y" or not is up for debate. But it may appeal to you.

Create a fake (in this case `handler`) to listen to the `ErrorOccurred` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var service = A.Fake<IService>();
    var consumer = new Consumer(service);

    var handler = A.Fake<EventHandler>();
    consumer.ErrorOccurred += handler;

    service.SomethingBadHappened += Raise.WithEmpty();

    A.CallTo(()=>handler.Invoke(A<object>._, A<EventArgs>._)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

That way you can check to see if the `handler` was called. There are straightforward modifications that could be made to ensure that the call was made a [specific number of times](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/assertion/#specifying-repeat), or with [certain arguments](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/).

Of course, if you don't care about the number of times the method was called, or the arguments, since there's really only one method of interest on `handler`, you could potentially use this simpler call, which will match *any* call to the handler (probably `Invoke`):

```
A.CallTo(handler).MustHaveHappened();
```